# Excel Sheet with existing Date style not working

Tags: java, excel

Need to fill data in Excel template , whcih has Date format style applied to cells. Somehow Date format is not reflecting after filling data in excel cell.

```
if (cellVal instanceof Date || cellVal instanceof Timestamp) {
cell.setCellValue("20-08-2019"));

CellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
 cell.setCellStyle(style);
}
```

Here   cell.getCellStyle()  to get existing cell style from excel template  which should convert date in this format: "20-AUG-19"

issue is even after appying this style  cell.setCellStyle(style), Date values style remained same i.e.  "20-08-2019"

Comment: Are you using `XSSFWorkBook` or `WorkBook`?

Comment: @ procrastinator XSSFWorkbook

Answer (score 0):

```
CellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
 cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

you are getting the style of `cell` variable and setting it again to `cell` so you're not changing anything at all.

your code should be like that:

```
CellStyle style = cellVal.getCellStyle(); //cellVal instead of cell
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Comment: But cell style is applied to cell created in excel template. so getting that by cell.getCellStyle();  where  cell = row.getCell(index);

Comment: can you please edit your question and add more code details.

Comment: Added example, please let me know if any solution.

Comment: in your code snippet [`cell.setCellValue("20-08-2019"))`] you set cell value to "20-08-2019" , then you get the style of that cell by `cell.getCellStyle()`, I don't see how this can convert the cell style to "20-AUG-19", if you can explain...